# use ruby to identify if array of terms contains one and ONLY one repeated term

Tags: ruby

In categorical logic, categorical syllogism requires four terms, but can only have three unique terms; that is one and ONLY one term can and must be repeated.

I trying to write a Ruby test for this but having a little bit of trouble.

Consider the following three arrays of terms, the first of which is a valid list, while the other two are invalid (termarray2 contains 4 unique terms and termarray3 contains only 2 unique terms).

```
termarray1 = ["Dogs", "Mortal Things", "Mortal Things", "Living Things"]
termarray2 = ["Dogs", "Mortal Things", "Cats", "Living Things"] 
termarray3 = ["Dogs", "Mortal Things", "Mortal Things", "Dogs"]
```

I want to write a test called `three_terms?`

It should return `true` for `termarray1` and `false` for `termarray2` and `termarray3`

Any ideas how I could to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the size of unique elements is `3` (using [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)):

```
array.uniq.size == 3
```

You could also monkey-patch `Array` with `three_terms?`:

```
class Array
  def three_terms?
    uniq.size == 3
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The `uniq` methods returns the unique elements in an array.

This should work:

```
array.uniq.count == 3
```

But the test you mention also checks that the original array has four elements. Thus the entire check should be:

```
(array.count == 4) && (array.uniq.count == 3)
```